# can the second thead row define the layout in a fixed table?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm working with a table that has the table-layout: fixed property as illustrated in the example below :

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="width:100%"> Hello there !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%">I</td>
            <td style="width:30%">AM</td>
            <td style="width:15%">STUCK</td>
            <td style="width:35%">!!!</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">E</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

As you can see if you run the snippet, the width property is ignored due to the fact that the layout is defined by the first row in thead.

If it is removed, the issue gets resolved as demonstrated below :

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%">I</td>
            <td style="width:30%">AM</td>
            <td style="width:15%">STUCK</td>
            <td style="width:35%">!!!</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">E</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Is there a way to make have a table head first row not define the layout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `colgroup` after your `table` tag. Define `width` and number of columns here

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
  <colgroup>
    <col span="1" style="width: 20%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 30%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
    <col span="1" style="width: 35%;">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"> Hello there !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>I</th>
      <th>AM</th>
      <th>STUCK</th>
      <th>!!!</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2">E</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    <col width="20%" />
    <col width="30%" />
    <col width="15%" />
    <col width="35%" />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"> Hello there !</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>I</th>
            <th>AM</th>
            <th>STUCK</th>
            <th>!!!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">E</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove "table-layout: fixed" from your table style.
Notice: you should also use `<th>` instead of `<td>` in `<thead>`

```html
<table border="1" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="width:100%"> Hello there !</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width:20%">I</td>
            <td style="width:30%">AM</td>
            <td style="width:15%">STUCK</td>
            <td style="width:35%">!!!</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>D</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2">E</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From what I remember, if I remove table-layout:fixed the content will still change the width of the columns unless i specify both a min and max width ?

Comment: @Vache this should not be the case unless you add another html tag with e.g. width or whitespace: no-wrap style